# JQuery Ajax - How to stop global error handler dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a global ajax error handler, here:

```
function SetAjaxErrorHandler() {
   $(document).ajaxError(function (event: JQueryEventObject, jqXHR: JQueryXHR, ajaxSettings: JQueryAjaxSettings, thrownError: string) {
       console.log("in error");
       // Call error API to log
       var url1 = appSettings["errorLogApiUrl"];
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url1 + "s",
           data: jqXHR.responseText,
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           error: (jqXhr) => {
            // I dont want the global error handler to be triggered here!
        }
    });
});
```

}

As you can see, on an event there is an error calling one of the other ajax calls on the page, I am trying to make another API call to log this on the server. However, if the call to log the error fails, I get caught in a recursive loop. 
So my question is, in my ajax call in the ajaxError() method, is there a way to stop the global error handler from being triggered?

tl;dr is there a way to use a global ajax error handler for some ajax calls but suppress it  for others?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can set `global` to `false` in the `$.ajax()` call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'path/to/url',
  global: false
});
```

From the [`.ajaxError()`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) docs:

> If [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/) or [`$.ajaxSetup()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) is called with the `global` option set to
>   `false`, the `.ajaxError()` method will not fire.

Answer (score 6):

From jQuery docs:

> If $.ajax() or $.ajaxSetup() is called with the global option set to false, the .ajaxError() method will not fire.

https://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

So add `global:false`

```
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url1 + "s",
       data: jqXHR.responseText,
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       global: false,
       error: (jqXhr) => {
        // I dont want the global error handler to be triggered here!
    }
```